# How to dump a tokyocabinet in-memory hashtable database in a file?

Tags: database, in-memory-database, in-memory, tokyo-cabinet, kyotocabinet

Is there a simply way to dump a tokyocabinet in-memory database to a file?
I didn't find anything about it in the tokyo documentation.
Does anyone know another nosql database that provide with this kind of thing? I'm looking for a very efficient in memory hashtable database, able to insert about 80000 records/sec. Dump to file would occur every 10 seconds.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I work for VoltDB.

While not a NoSQL Database, VoltDB can be used as a KV store and also there is an "export" functionality that you can use to setup continuous movement of data to CSV files. On the other hand, if your goal is to just have persistent VoltDB has a feature called command logging which takes snapshots periodically and between snapshots maintains command logs for zero data loss.

As for the throughput requirement of 80K TPS, that can be easily achieved with very commodity hardware. For example, my Macbook Pro can do about 60K TPS.

If you have any questions, feel free to reach out to me directly at dremella(at)voltdb(dot)com.

Cheers